# libXML2 for 64 bit Visual C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, libxml2

I have X86 Visual C++ project that uses `libxml2` library. It run fine when project is set to x86 architecture, but fails with errors with x64 one:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_xmlCheckVersion    usingLibXML 
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_xmlReadFile    usingLibXML 
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_xmlFreeDoc usingLibXML 
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_xmlDocGetRootElement   usingLibXML 
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_xmlCleanupParser   usingLibXML
```

I suppose I have 32 Bit `libxml2` library while I need to have 64bit one. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. I get `libxml2` by performing following steps:

I cloned source from `https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2`

And build:

```
cd \libxml2\win32
cscript configure.js compiler=msvc prefix=c:\opt include=c:\opt\include lib=c:\opt\lib debug=yes iconv=no
nmake /f Makefile.msvcls
```

How to get 64 bit `libxml` library? How to build 64 bit application with libxml support?

Comment: Are you sure you set up the `includes` in the property pages correct? Check your projects property page and tell me what platform is selected from the top right hand corner. Also, there is a port for `libxml2` on vcpkg, so I'd suggest using it (or Conan) to get the libraries you require.

Comment: Also, verify that the include/include paths are set for the correct platform (in this case `x64`)

Comment: I have the same value in "Additional Include Directories" in both - x64 and x86 bit configurations.  I use the same [headers](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/tree/master/include/libxml) for x64 and x86 systems. Should I use different one? Where I can get headers for x64 then?

Comment: Make sure you build from the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt", or follow the steps for your MSVC version to set up an x64 compiler on the command line.